# Proxmox 5.2 Gemini Lake and IGD (graphics) pass through for Ubuntu 18

Tags: intel, proxmox

I’m trying to set up a fresh install of Proxmox 5.2 on Gemini Lake and I would like to configure a VM with IGD (graphics) passthrough for Ubuntu 18

Computer-based on ASRock J4105-ITX asrock.com/mb/Intel/J4105-ITX/

A standard install is working properly and now I would like to use HDMI output for a VM with Ubuntu 18.

I have read all this information:

- https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Pci_passthrough
- https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/guide-intel-intergrated-graphic-passthrough.30451/
- https://redhat.com/archives/vfio-users/2017-April/msg00032.html
- https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/proxmox-5-0-kaby-lake-and-igd-graphics-passthrough-for-windows-10.36165/

My setup is like this:

1. Fresh install Proxmox 5.2
2. Grub:

   ```
   vim /etc/default/grub
   ```

   Change the

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT
   ```

   line to

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet intel_iommu=on video=efifb=off,vesafb=off"`
   ```

   Save and quit

   ```
   update-grub
   ```
3. Blacklist module:

   ```
   vim /etc/modprobe.d/pve-blacklist.conf
   ```

   Add these lines:

   ```
   blacklist snd_hda_intel
   blacklist snd_hda_codec_hdmi
   blacklist i915
   ```

   Save and quit
4. VFIO:

   ```
   vim /etc/modules
   ```

   Add these lines:

   ```
   vfio
   vfio_iommu_type1
   vfio_pci
   vfio_virqfd
   save and quit
   ```
5. Vga adapter:

   ```
   lspci -n -s 00:02
   lspci command display 00:02.0 0300: 8086:3185 (rev 03)
   vim /etc/modprobe.d/vfio.conf
   ```

   Add this line:

   ```
   options vfio-pci ids=8086:3185
   ```

   Save and quit
6. `update-initramfs -u`
7. VM:

   Create a VM (id = 100) with an Ubuntu 18 iso as the primary boot

   Change the setup for the VM:

   ```
   vim /etc/pve/qemu-server/100.conf
   ```

   Add these lines:

   ```
   machine: pc-i440fx-2.2
   args: -device vfio-pci,host=00:02.0,addr=0x02
   vga: none
   ```

   Save and quit
8. Reboot the server
9. Start VM 100

Video output is initialised (clear screen) just after the VM 100 is started but the screen remains black. Start task log is:

```
no efidisk configured! Using temporary efivars disk.
kvm: -device vfio-pci,host=00:02.0,addr=0x02,x-igd-gms=1,x-igd-opregion=on: IGD device 0000:00:02.0 has no ROM, legacy mode disabled
TASK OK
```

I try to install Ubuntu before change config, but it doesn't help.

What should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

You are running your VM with UEFI and legacy BIOS. The machine type to use with UEFI is q35 and not i440fx. 
You should either change the BIOS type to SeaBIOS or change the machine type to q35. 
If you go with UEFI machine you should add EFI disk from the "Add Hardware" menu.